# Currency/monetary values -- How to store in a DB & transfer using JSON?

Tags: json, postgresql, currency

What are the best practices for storing currency/monetary values in the DB, processing them in a server-side app, and finally sending them down to the browser via a JSON API?

I've figured two approaches, but I'm not sure how to weigh out the pros & cons:

### Store values as integers in the smallest monetary unit

- Basically this means that the database will store the monetary value in cents / paise / shillings / etc.
- The server side app will map this value to a regular integer variable.
- The JSON API will represent the value as a regular JSON number.
- The downside of this approach is that you have to constantly divide by 100 before displaying a monetary value to the user and always multiply by 100 before storing any user input.
- Possible gotchas: How do you define the smallest monetary unit? Is it on the basis of two decimal points or four? Is there any currency which does not have a 100:1 ratio, i.e. 100 cents = 1 dollar.

### Store values as decimal/numeric with fixed precision & scale

- The DB stores the monetary value as a decimal/numeric type with a fixed precision & scale, eg. NUMERIC(10,2)
- The server-side app maps these to special objects which can preserve the precision & scale across computations, eg. `BigDecimal` in Ruby.
- The JSON API exchanges these values as *strings* and not numbers. Because numbers would automatically get parsed as floats by the JSON parser, thus causing loss in precision.
- The downside of this approach is that all computations on the server-side need to happen within a boxed data-type (possibly slower) AND that the JSON parsers needs to be aware of the the fact that certain strings are not actually strings, but numeric values.
- The upside of this is that you don't need to constantly multiply and divide by 100.

Is there a generally accepted best practice for this?

Answer (score 5):

There are two additional gotchas for both practices.

Firstly, not all currencies need two decimals. Many need three. Many more need zero. And some field-specific apps, e.g. finance and forex, need 5 or 6.

Secondly, some currencies have colorful conversion rates for subdenominations. Old-school rupees, for instance, converted to 16 annas, 64 paise or 192 pies. Luckily, only two countries retain this kind of crazy conversions rates if wikipedia is anything to go by -- Mauritania where 1 ouguiya = 5 khoums, and Madagascar where 1 ariary = 5 iraimbilanja.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimalisation

The point, though, is that you shouldn't be too US-centric in your assumptions if you plan to ever localize your app. At the very least, consider the use-cases where you've 0, 2 and 3 decimals, and chew a bit on what path you'd want to take if you ever went international. Just in case.

As an aside, also note that the `numeric` type in Postgres can be stored without specifying a precision. It takes no more room to do so, since it'll reside in the extended storage when too large just the same. And, much like `varchar` is better than `varchar(n)`, it'll be faster because you'll skip the built-in precision check when storing your numbers (which, in this case, needs to be sane indeed).

As for which of the two approaches that you describe is best, I've seen more of the second -- in a simplified form.

I'd stress three points:

1. Storing currency as `numeric`, with or without a precision, makes sense in the DB, for the sake of not introducing rounding errors when generating accounts and reports. (There is a built-in money type, too, but I've never it seen used in practice for all sorts of very valid reasons.)
2. Speed should be the least of your worries if you actually need the kind of precision that overflows a bigint or a double-precision float (the latter of which is used by js and json for floating point numbers, if memory serves). If this is your case, arbitrary precision maths is the way to go, from one end to the other.
3. Typical apps that manipulate typical currency amounts will never run into these overflow limits. Take a cold hard look here. Unless you're planning to store amounts in quadrillions of US dollars, converting unbounded numerics to string and back to pass them around in json is a sign that you're over-engineering your app. If this is your case, just stick to double-precision floats and ship your app.

Comment: +1 for "Mauritania where 1 ouguiya = 5 khoums, and Madagascar where 1 ariary = 5 iraimbilanja." Never would've figured that out!

Comment: Thank you for the link to the Wikipedia article on decimalization of currencies. For all practical reasons, no currency will exist (at least in our system) with non-decimal currencies. The matter of 100:1 and 1000:1 still remains.

Comment: I agree with your comment regarding speed. Storing monetary values as `NUMERIC` is not going to impact performance in any significant way. However, I didn't understand your reasoning. Why do you recommend arbitrary precision math? Isn't that something we're trying to avoid wrt monetary calculations?

Comment: "converting unbounded numerics to string and back to pass them around in json is a sign that you're over-engineering your app" >> If I don't do some string-related magic and pass `NUMERIC`s as-is, they're parsed as float by JS. If you simply try doing 1.13*5 in your browser you'll get back an in-exact result. There are a lot of places in my app where monetary values are being manipulated in the browser (eg. user-generated invoices), and treating them as floats may lead to weird bugs. What's your take on this?

Comment: If you need to store an amount of money that doesn't comfortably fit as a double, and actually care about keeping the precision in that case, you need end-to-end arbitrary precision math. In almost all apps, you don't need to.

Comment: Re floats, to the best of my knowledge, js uses double precision floats (15 digits) rather than single precision (7 digits). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008 -- I.e. don't worry about the json/js if that is the case, but I'll admit I haven't touched js in a while and might recollect wrongly.

Comment: Re #3 in your answer. I went with the approach of passing currency values as plain ol' JS numbers in JSON (as opposed to strings). When parsed by the browser these get converted to floats and sometimes that leads to inexact representations (which is fine, because while displaying them I'm rounding them off to the precision required by the user). However, when it posts those numbers back to the app, the come back as plain ol' inexact JS floats. Now, the app, in Ruby, barfs on them because BigDecimal can't "digest" floats without being given a precision. However, it can easily handle strings.

Comment: What kind of numbers are causing issues?

Comment: Numbers are not causing issues in the browser as the range of monetary values I'm dealing with is much lesser than the range of the double data-type. However, when a number like 46.66666667 is sent *back* to the server as a regular number, the Ruby BigDecimal class barfs because it cannot handle raw floats without explicitly specifying a precision. BigDecimal.new(46.6667) will not work, however BigDecimal.new('46.6667') will work.

Comment: You have me scratching my head on why you might need 8 digits of currency precision for to start with -- the only apps I'm aware of that need 5 or 6 are used in financial exchanges. Shouldn't that get rounded to 2 or 3 digits, avoiding the need to mess around with the BigDecimal type altogether?

Comment: In Rails/ActiveRecord a NUMERIC (Postgres) data-field automatically gets mapped to a BigDecimal. And BigDecimal does not accept floats without manually specifying the precision. And the JSON sent down the wire has a float without the precision. And so it goes :-)

Comment: Basically, I'm bothered with only up to 4 placed after the decimal point. However as long as the JSON coming down the wire is a Float (even with less than 4 precision), BigDecimal will refuse to *automatically* accept it.

Comment: Ah, makes more sense. I'm not familiar enough with ActiveRecord to be of much help, but is it not possible to change the setter or the constructor accordingly, so you don't need to worry about it?